# What is the use of classical metaphors in literal situations called?

Tags: phrase-usage, figures-of-speech

For instance:

> Gravity keeps you down-to-earth!

This was the only example I could say off the top of my head. However, I've seen this done a couple of times.

It's a kind of play on the word *down-to-earth*—words and phrases that are usually intended as a metaphor being used so literally.

#### What is this phenomenon called?

Comment: It is a *pun* (17th century- etymology unknown) or *play on words*.

Comment: The earliest reference the OED has to a *pun* is from 1644, which post-dates Shakespeare by nearly 30 years. I mention this since the Bard was one of literature's greatest exponents of the *play on words* e.g. the opening lines of *Richard III* - "*Now is the winter of our discontent made glorious summer by this sun of York*", where the speaker Richard is referring to himself, a son of the House of York.

Answer (score 2):

Such a play on words is called a [*pun* or *paronomasia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) (Greek: lit. "name change"). It may, as here, depend upon literalizing a metaphor or upon exploiting the near or exact homographs or homophones so frequent in English.

> A pair of hunters, one from Prague, the other from Vienna, were attacked and devoured by hungry bears, a large male and his mate. A pathologist determined that the Czech was in the male.

Comment: Guess somebody didn't like the joke!

Comment: LMAO. Fantastic joke, that one!